# Nginx Symfony2 Staging Config

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

i'm trying to configure nginx to serve several releases of one symfony project.

Releasefolder structure:
/var/www/my-project/releases/24/
/var/www/my-project/releases/46/
/var/www/my-project/releases/47/

I'd like to call a URL like "http://my-server/my-project/release/47" which should access /var/www/my-project/releases/47/web/app.php on the server.

I tried for a while now but couldn't find the final solution, any help would be great!

My last try:

```
server {
    server_name my-server;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri $uri$2app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ /my-project/release/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/app\.php(/|$) {
        root /var/www/my-project/releases/$1/web;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/app.php;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/my-project_$1_error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/my-project_$1_access.log;

        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }
}
```

This config produces following error:

> [error] 2272#0: *169 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/my-project/release/47app.phpapp.phpapp.phpapp.phpapp.phpapp.phpapp.phpapp.phpapp.phpapp.phpapp.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, unfortunately i couln't get it working. I think i have to learn more about nginx configuration generally to be able to handle such problems, before i can use it in production.

My workaround for my problem is to create an own nginx conf per release. The file will be created at build process, is then transfered to the webserver, copied to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/[releasename].conf` and activated by `sudo service nginx reload`.

A deinstallation script within the release dir removes sources and config, when release no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `root` directive in your `server` container -- is `/var/www` the default on your architecture? Otherwise, add a root directive:

```
root /var/www;
```

`try_files` is failing for find a match and will rewrite the URL by appending `app.php` to it. The resulting URL does not match your other location block, so it gets rewritten again and again.

The final term on your `try_files` directive is wrong. You have `$2` where `/web/` should be (probably inherited from a previous experiment).

Using `try_files` to make a general rewrite is a bad idea, as any mistyped URL could lead to a rewrite loop. Try:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^(/my-project/release/[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1/app.php;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, your answer brought me some steps further!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the config to this:

```
server {
    server_name my-server;
    root /var/www;

    location / {
        rewrite ^(/my-project/release/[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1/app.php;
    }

    location ~ /my-project/release/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/app\.php(/|$) {
        alias /var/www/my-project/releases/$1/web;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/app.php;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;

        error_log /var/www/my-project/releases/$1/app/logs/nginx_error.log;
        access_log /var/www/my-project/releases/$1/app/logs/nginx_access.log;

        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }
}
```

Now a call like "http://my-server/my-project/release/47" points correctly to "/var/www/my-project/releases/47/web/app.php".

The problem is now that the url "my-project/release/47" arrives at symfony router which can't find a route to this url.

What is now the right way to keep the url showing up like "//my-server/my-project/release/47" at browser but arrives at symfony as "//my-server/"?

Comment: I am not familiar with symfony, but the URL is probably passed to it via the `fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;` parameter in your `fastcgi_params` file. Perhaps you could try explicitly setting the value to `/my-server`.